Does this equation imply "non-linear" waves?
For one-dimensional bounded domain $x \in [0, L]$ consider
$\partial_{t} v = -\frac{1}{\rho}\partial_{x}\rho  - v $
$\partial_{t} \rho = -\partial_{x}(\rho v)$
with initial and boundary data as $v(0, t)=v(L, t)=0$ and $\rho(x, 0) = \rho_{0} + \frac{x}{L}$
What type of solutions are implied by this problem ? Can we expect "non-linear" modes in the sense of modes interacting and exchanging energies (i.e shock waves or similar, solitons..) ?

Are you familiar with the method of characteristics? It is used specifically for nonlinear transport equations of this type in one spatial dimension

Could you please name a reference/book where I can find the characteristics of this equation ? I know the method of characteristics.

Is it $- v \partial_{x} \rho$ or $- \partial_{x}(\rho v)$ in the second equation?

It is the partial derivative of the product, I have now improved the notation.

See wave propagation and reflection in numerical simulation Numerical solution
